# How to create a view to list all unpublished page in library?

Tags: publishing-page, view

It maybe a SharePoint dummy level question for but I cannot find a way to do it.

In the Pages library we have enabled publishing feature. Only major version 1.0, 2.0, 3.0... are published and minor version are draft. I want to create a view to show all unpublished pages (and another view for all published pages). I can add a column shows version number only.

Can I accomplish it without programming?

Comment: Try with this [unpublished-view](http://thechriskent.com/2013/02/14/unpublished-view/)

Answer (score 5):

Without code

On library click *Create new view* based on for ex. *All items.*
Check columns you want to view and sort it how you like.

**Under Filter**

click *Show items only when the following is true*

**Approval Status** ---
**is greater than** --- 
**0** << this is for all unpublished(Rejected, Pending, Draft)

Click OK

For Published view create one more view with

**Approval Status** ---
**is equal to** --- 
**0** << this is for published(Approved)

And that's it

[Reference](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/michael_yeager/archive/2008/11/03/reference-list-for-internal-field-names.aspx)

**Display Name** ---    Approval Status

**Internal Name** ---   _ModerationStatus

**GUID** ---    {fdc3b2ed-5bf2-4835-a4bc-b885f3396a61}

**Type** --- ModStat

---

*FYI*

**Status    ---  Internal Value**

Approved    --- 0

Rejected    --- 1

Pending --- 2

Draft   --- 3

Scheduled  --- 4

---

EDIT

With code

[unpublished-view](http://thechriskent.com/2013/02/14/unpublished-view/)

In the Code view just paste the following into your View’s XML inside the Query element:

```
<Where>
<Or>
    <Eq>
        <FieldRef Name="_ModerationStatus"/>
        <Value Type="ModStat">Draft</Value>
    </Eq>
    <IsNotNull>
        <FieldRef Name="CheckoutUser"/>
    </IsNotNull>
</Or>
</Where>
```

---

**EDIT FINAL**

**If content Approval is disabled** you can't see Approval status in edit view under filters so you must add it in code for that 2 new views (published.aspx and draft.aspx).
Open SPDesigner and go to Pages/forms and edit that view. Find `<Query>` and paste that code after  `<Query>`

For Draft view:

```
<Where>
<Or>
    <Eq>
        <FieldRef Name="_ModerationStatus"/>
        <Value Type="ModStat">Draft</Value>
    </Eq>
    <IsNotNull>
        <FieldRef Name="CheckoutUser"/>
    </IsNotNull>
</Or>
</Where>
```

For Publish view:

```
<Where>
<Or>
    <Eq>
        <FieldRef Name="_ModerationStatus"/>
        <Value Type="ModStat">Approved</Value>
    </Eq>
    <IsNotNull>
        <FieldRef Name="CheckoutUser"/>
    </IsNotNull>
</Or>
</Where>
```

*You can set 3 for Draft and 0 for Approved for _ModerationStatus value.

Save file and that's it. :)

Comment: I have not enabled content approval for Pages library. Will it still work?

Comment: Try without.
Library > Library Settings;
  
Versioning Settings;

Content Approval : **Yes**;

Document Version History : **Create major and minor (draft) versions**;

Comment: So I must enable content approval?

Comment: You don't need to enable Content Approval.
And then value for status Approved is 0 and for Draft status is 3. If you enable Content Approval then you have more statuses. Rejceted is 1, Pending is 2 and Scheduled is 4.

Comment: If Content Approval is enabled you can edit view from UI and if Content Approval is disabled you must edit view through code (see EDIT FINAL in my answer)

Answer (score 0):

The other easiest method is to create a calculated column with formula `=IF((Version-INT(Version))<>0,"Draft","Published")` and use the column in a view.

For detailed explanation you can visit [this](https://blog.binarybits.net/programming/sharepoint/view-unpublished-pages-or-draft-pages-or-published-pages-in-sharepoint/) article.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, **the current answers are not applicable for SharePoint Online and approval turned off**
(... and no programming with e.g. PnP.PowerShell against my SPO pages library).

When turning on approval like [Marko Tica](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/31714/marko-tica) recommended (with nice insights in approval status values), I could create the filtered view with approval status, but after removing approval from the library settings, the column was gone and the view did not work anymore.

The solution of [Kannan](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/22379/kannan) with a calculated field I liked, but it seems, that in SPO pages library, you cannot reference the Version field in the UI. By the way, I had to look up the referenced blog article, the updated link is now [here](https://blog.binarybits.net/view-unpublished-pages-or-draft-pages-or-published-pages-in-sharepoint/).

I ended up just creating a view that is sorting descending by Modified date to have most unpublished pages on top for easier selecting when bulk publishing ... :/

Comment: So, **you can create different views by the version number**, as it is always ending with ".0" for published items.

So, for the "Published" view, you would need a filter "version ends with '.0' ", which is not available, but you could use the Filter criteria "version contains '.0' "

For the "Unpublished" view, you would need a "version does not end with '.0'", which does also not exist, but you can add additional columns to the filter criteria, so that you have 9 filters combined by OR which result in "version contains '.1' OR '.2' OR '.3' OR '.4' OR '.5' OR '.6' OR '.7' OR '.8' OR '.9'"